# Concurrent Access HashMap

Tags: java

The code below runs into the issue of `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. Is there any way to prevent this or allow this?

```
public void saveHomes() throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter br;
    br  = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(homeFile));
    Map<String, Location> homesLoc;

    System.out.println(homes2.keySet());
    for (String player : homes2.keySet()) {
        homesLoc = homes2.get(player);
        for (String name : homesLoc.keySet()) {
            br.write(player + " " + homesLoc.get(name) + " " + name);
            br.newLine();
            br.flush();
        }
    }

    br.close();
}
```

Comment: yes, don't modify the map while you are iterating through it.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the answers here seem to have misunderstood the meaning of `ConcurrentModificationException`, making them incomplete or even incorrect answers.

First thing you need to understand is, `ConcurrentModificationException` has nothing to do with concurrent access to the collection by multiple threads.  It can happen even in a single-threaded application.  So, using synchronized `Map` implementations is NOT a correct solution for the problem.

`ConcurrentModificationException` happens mostly when

1. You get an iterator from a collection
2. The collection is structurally modified, making your iterator no longer valid
3. If you use the iterator now, it will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Therefore, even the `Map` is accessed by single thread, you may still have problem.

From your code, there is no obvious logic that modified the collections (`homes2` / `homesLoc`).  That may be caused by

1. It is modified in another thread, which we cannot see in your code, or
2. The `Map` is an implementation that, even a get() is treated as structural modified.  Access-ordered LinkedHashMap is an example.  (we cannot see in your code either)

There are different solutions, depending on your need:

1. using `ConcurrentHashMap`, which guarantees that iterator is not throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`.  Iteration will be base on the order at the time iterator is created
2. if it is another thread updating the map which cause the problem, you may also consider proper synchronization control on the map when you are iterating through it
3. if it is caused by Access-Ordered `LinkedHashMap`, you may simply change a bit in your logic, by iterating through `yourMap.entries()`, so that you don't need to use extra `get()` to get the value.

Answer (score 3):

This is a wheel that's already been invented:

Use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Using it instead of a (non-threadsafe) `HashMap` will make your concurrency problems go away.

Comment: although using ConcurrentHashMap will fix the problem, the reasoning in the answer is not correct.  ConcurrentModificationException has nothing to do with threadsafe/non-threadsafe.

Comment: @AdrianShum it absolutely does have to do with it, because clearly in the foreach loops above the collection is not being modified by that thread. Thus, it must be getting modified by an external thread which is triggering the ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: well, it is not necessary true :) please see my answer: it is possible for a `get()` being a structural change which cause ConcurrentModificationException.  Although I believe quite probably the problem is caused by update of another thread, over-generalizing the problem by saying it is caused by non-threadsafe HashMap may lead to incorrect understanding of ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: and... again, it has nothing to do with threadsafe/non-threadsafe: a threadsafe map implementation will still produce ConcurrentModificationException.  ConcurrentHashMap is fine not because it is thread-safe, it is because the way it create/maintain the iterator.

Comment: Well, LinkedHashMap with accessOrder is a scary thing! I am aware of ConcurrentModificationException not always having to do with multiple threads, but I also never realized LinkedHashMap could cause that with a simple foreach loop :O!

Comment: @jyro117 more specific, it is **access-ordered** LinkedHashMap to be blamed :P (a bit off topic) IMHO, it is not a good idea to loop thru the keyset of a map and then do a get().  Looping thru map.entries() is better choice in such case.  Not only for avoiding the rare ConcurrentModificationException for access-ordered linkedhashmap, but also for better performance and more correct result (e.g. when looping thru a ConcurrentHashMap, and in middle of loop an element is removed by another thread.  Calling map.get() will give you null while looping thru map.entries() will give you desired result)

Answer (score 1):

"Java Collection classes are fail-fast which means that if the Collection will be changed while some thread is traversing over it using iterator, the iterator.next() will throw a ConcurrentModificationException."

You are changing homesLoc and then traversing it.

Comment: I don't quite see how I'm changing it. homesLoc.get(name) doesn't modify the contents of homesLoc, does it?

Comment: I'm referring to this: homesLoc = homes2.get(player);

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should use a hashmap for this since you are just iterating through it, but in java a hashtable is synchronized so that should get rid of the concurrent access problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should use an `java.util.Iterator` to iterate through the keyset. This will prevent a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

Code:

```
public void saveHomes() throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter br;
    br  = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(homeFile));
    Map<String, Location> homesLoc;

    System.out.println(homes2.keySet());
    Iterator<String> players = homes2.keySet().iterator();

    while (players.hasNext()) {
        String player = players.next();
        homesLoc = homes2.get(player);

        Iterator<String> names = homesLoc.keySet().iterator();
        while (names.hasNext()) {
            String name = names.next();
            br.write(player + " " + homesLoc.get(name) + " " + name);
            br.newLine();
            br.flush();
        }
    }

    br.close();
}
```